# Two Bootstrap modal windows - no input focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, modal-dialog, focus

I have two Boostrap modal windows opened (it happens on a page which usually displays one modal (a survey or something), but displays a second one if a user is not logged in). The links and buttons on the second modal (login modal) work fine, but I cannot get the input fields to focus. I tried messing arround with autofocus, .focus() and similar stuff, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

EDIT: Solved it by removing tab-index from modals. Input fields started working fine after that.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: Solved it by removing tab-index from modals. Input fields started working fine after that.